# Создание выборки для обучение нейронной сети по классификации изображений

Tags: python, изображения, нейронные-сети, классификация

Мне нужно создать выборку для обучения моей нейронной сети классификации изображений. Так как тема достаточно специфичная, готовых изображений очень мало. Как из одного изображения получить достаточное количество? Есть ли готовые решения для изменения четкости изображения, его поворота и т.д.?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation

Comment: Ну, обычно берут изображения и чуть-чуть их видоизменяют - наклоны, изменения размера, могут шум вносить, много чего может быть, но сильно зависит от того, что у вас вообще за картинки и что вы ожидаете на входе модели после обучения.

Answer (score 2):

Функция для аугментации изображений:

```
def augment(image, label):
    new_height = new_width = 32 # размер изображения
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (new_height, new_width))

    if tf.random.uniform((), minval=0, maxval=1) < 0.1:
        image = tf.tile(tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image), [1, 1, 3]) # с вероятностью 0.1 делаем изображение серым

    image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, max_delta=0.1)
    image = tf.image.random_contrast(image, lower=0.1, upper=0.2)

    # a left upside down flipped is still a dog ;)
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)  # 50%
    # image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image) #%50%

    return image, label
```

Если датасет в виде tf.tensor, применить к нему эту функцию можно так:

```
ds_augmented = ds_train.map(augment)
```

Функция не дополняет датасет, а изменяет его. Поэтому к исходному датасету нужно добавить изменённый.
(Источник: [видео](https://youtu.be/8wwfVV7ixyY))